# Error Sintáctico Bash Accediendo Array

Tags: array, bash, script

Estoy aprendiendo lo básico de `scripts` y me han mandado hacer un script que dando un directorio como parámetro calcule la suma de los `bytes` de los archivos de dicho directorio ignorando los subdirectorios que contenga.Me limitan las funciones que puedo usar a ls y awk(no me permiten usar `grep,find,wc...etc`)

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
cd $1
allbytes=$(ls -l | awk '{print $5}')
alldata=$(ls)
bytes=0
len=${#allbytes[*]}
i=0

while [ $i -lt $len ]
do
    if [ ! -d "${alldata[$i]}" ]
    then
        let "bytes= $bytes + ${allbytes[${i}]}"
    fi
    let "i=$i + 1"
done
echo $bytes
```

> El error dice:./exercici1.sh: línea 12: let: bytes= 0 + 
>   268840
>   68
>   595
>   4096
>   3550
>   6026
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   7882
>   4096
>   14696
>   3965
>   18480
>   46764
>   31736
>   573
>   190
>   268840: error sintáctico en la expresión (el elemento de error es "68
>   595
>   4096
>   3550
>   6026
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   4096
>   7882
>   4096
>   14696
>   3965
>   18480
>   46764
>   31736
>   573
>   190
>   268840")
>   268840

Entiendo el error como que no accede al valor del Array que marco con el índice pero no entiendo el porqué...Si me ayudarais lo agradecería.

Comment: Me parece una barbaridad hacer un ejercicio así parseando la salida de `ls`. Recomiendo leer [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), donde se explica la fragilidad de tal método. De hecho, con un simple `du` podrías sacar buena parte de esta info. O, si quieres ir fichero a fichero, con `stat`.

Comment: @fedorqui se que sería más fácil con otros comandos pero me dicen explícitamente de usar esos comandos para ello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tiene tu script es que has definido mal los `arrays` y no son tales, sino simples cadenas. Modifica esto:

```
allbytes=$(ls -l | awk '{print $5}')
alldata=$(ls)
```

por

```
allbytes=($(ls -l | awk '{print $5}'))
alldata=($(ls))
```

Observa que enceramos todo en nuevos paréntesis para ahora sí indicar que el contenido es un `array`. Por otro lado, si te permiten usar `ls` y `awk` por que no lo resuelves todo desde `awk`, por ejemplo:

```
len=$(ls -l | gawk 'BEGIN{total=0}$1!~/d/{total = total + $5}END{print total}')
```

Lo único particular es un patrón de búsqueda `$1!~/d/` para quitar de la suma los directorios